# Upstream and downstream problem using relative velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

> On a river coast, there is a port; when a barge passed the port, a motor boat departed from the port to a village at the distance $S_1 = 15$ km downstream. It reached its destination after $t = 45$ mins, turned around, and started immediately moving back towards the starting point. At the distance $S_2 = 9$ km from the village, it met the barge. What is the speed of the river water, and what is the speed of the boat with respect to the water? Note that the barge did not move with respect to the water.

<sup>*(Source: Jaan Kalda IPHO notes)*</sup>

This is of course an easy problem and can be easily solved by writing the distance travelled by boat in upstream and downstream motion.
But the solution given in the book is very different. It involves the idea of relative motion. The author wrote that “In the water’s frame of reference, it is clear that departing from the barge and returning to it took exactly the same amount of time.”

Proof of this fact:
Working in water’s frame of reference, we see that the barge is at rest and the boat is travelling with uniform speed throughout the journey. Also,  In the downstream and upstream motion, change in relative position will be equal and opposite. So, departing from the barge and returning to it took exactly the same amount of time.

Although I have proved this fact, I can’t understand why does the proof work. I mean to ask how can we look at this result in an intuitive way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the intuition. Imagine the log is a super long one. Let the motorboat be YOU, standing at one end of the log, doesn't matter which end. Then you start walking from one end to the other end of the log. And then you walk back. Time taken is the same for both legs for a simple reason - you are walking the same (relative) distance with the same (walking) speed either way.

Answer (score -2):

For me, it seems obvious that speed of boat w.r.t river (or equivalently barge) remains same upstream and downstream.

See, If instead of a river it was another boat, then while moving in same direction relative speed seems lower and while moving towards each other, relative speed seems higher. But here, the boat is slowed down due to the river.

*While moving downsteam*

speed of boat = $v_b + v_r$

relative speed = $(v_b + v_r) - v_r=v_b$

*while moving upstream*

speed of boat = $v_r-v_b$ (without changing coordinate axes)

relative speed = $(v_r-v_b) - v_r=-v_b$